# Easiest way to set all char array values to the same value

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, arrays

I've looked and found no definitive answer. I'm looking for the easiest way to set all array elements in a char array to '*'.

```
public static int GridWidth = 7;
public static int GridHeight = 5;

char[,] Cave = new char[GridWidth, GridHeight]
```

So i have a multi dimensional array and want to set all of the elements to '*'. Is this a case of iterating through the array to set each of the values, or is there alternative methods?

Comment: *I'm looking for the easiest way*. Do you think any more easiest way exist than for loop?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel : Yes, `FillArray(Cave, '*')`

Comment: @HenkHolterman Unfortunately this is c# :p

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - I know.

Answer (score 1):

Running double for each loop is the easiest way to initialise 2 dimensional array at the moment.

```
for(int i = 0; i< GridWidth; i++)
   for(int j = 0; j< GridHeight; j++)
      Cave[i,j] = '*'
```

Comment: How can i prevent this from an IndexOutOfRangeException?

Comment: add this line atop char[,] Cave = new char[GridWidth, GridHeight]

Answer (score 0):

I would have gone with the two loops myself and the following would definitely not be easier than for loops:

One liner LINQ:

```
 Enumerable.Range(0, GridWidth)
.AsParallel()
.ForAll(s => Enumerable.Range(0, GridHeight)
.AsParallel()
.ForAll(p => Cave[s, p] = '*'));
```